# unknown props message in console while using redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

im using redux form for react application. im facing this warning in console on rendering of form

```
warning: Unknown props `initialValue`, `autofill`, `onUpdate`, `valid`, `invalid`, `dirty`, `pristine`, `active`, `touched`, `visited`, `autofilled` on <input> tag. Remove these props from the element.
```

how to resolve this warning in redux form

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This warning was [introduced in React 15.2.0](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html) to prevent people from passing down unnecessary or invalid props. Redux form did this, which probably is why you see the warning. There's a [closed issue](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1249) for it on their issue tracker on GitHub if you want to read more. It should be fixed in [this version](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/releases/tag/v6.0.0-rc.2), so try updating and the warning should go away.

Answer (score 2):

```
const renderField = field => (
  <div>
    <input {...field.input}/>
                 // ^^^^^^------------------ THAT is all you have to add. 
    {field.touched && field.error && <span>{field.error}</span>}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: super useful abbreviation, just needs some context and a link!